# Fastest way to add numbers in a very large arithmetic series?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to minimize overhead as much as possible when adding numbers in an arithmetic series. I'm talking about a very large set, such as from 1 to 2^128. Is there any fast way of doing this? If so, what would it be without actually using the arithmetic sequence sum formula? Just as a reference, the sum from 1 to 2^128 is:

57896044618658097711785492504343953926464851149359812787997104700240680714240

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Comment: "without actually using the arithmetic sequence sum formula"

Comment: That sounds like an artificial limitation. That is in fact the only reasonable way to do this. Is there a particular reason why the formula can't be used?

Comment: Nope. I'm taking a digital logic class, and I was given this as a challenge question (not homework). Apparently my professor was able to compute the value in under 10 second (without the formula), and it's actually driving me crazy.

Comment: Summing up all the numbers sequentially isn't going to finish in anyone's lifetime. And there isn't much of a middle-ground between brute-force, and applying the formula... So it seems that the project might be misguided?

Comment: I'm guessing so. I was thinking of using some type of reference or pointer (or make use of iterators somehow) instead of changing the "sum" variable over and over in a loop. Eh, I'll just wait it out until when my professor tells us how to do it. It's not homework so it doesn't matter, but man I've been obsessing over it all afternoon.

Comment: In this case, the sum is just `2^255 + 2^127`.  Is the puzzle just to output that in base 10?

Comment: May I ask how you came to that? EDIT: Nvm. That's actually pretty clever. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the professor wants you to go at it from a bit-shifting/manipulation perspective, rather than integer formulas?

Comment: @peachykeen what do you mean?

Comment: As Nemo noted, this particular one is `2^(2n) + 2^(n-1)`, which can be done very easily by `n = log2(x)`. Is that coincidental, or does a similar bit/power-of-2 related solution hold?

Comment: His particular case seems to be 2^(2n-1) + 2^(n-1). But this doesn't seem to hold for any other particular power. I tried with n=32, for example.

Comment: It's not possible at all. Even if one addition would be performed with 1 processor operation you will need more than 10^15 years of computation on most powerful supercomputers of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Only fast way is to use the formula:

```
n * (n+1) / 2
```

Any other method (adding naively) will take way too long! (Even if you had a million years on a supercomputer, you wouldn't finish the calculation).

For such a large integer though, you cannot use normal integers. You will need to use a big integer object. So get a Big Integer library, eg. [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=c%2B%2B+bigint), https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/.

Note: a 256-bit integer may be able to hold results up to around that scale, but it is quite platform and compiler-dependent, as to whether 256-bit integers are readily available, and how they are used.